# Where is the /blog/ url set from?

Tags: templates

I'm having a weird issue while setting up a site. It almost seems as though the /blog/ url is reserved or already in use, only it isn't as far as I can tell.

I setup a new page called 'Blog' and set the permalink to '/blog/'. Then under 'Settings' => 'Reading' I set the Posts page to be 'Blog'. Then I went one step further and setup a new template called 'tpl-blog.php' and assigned it to the 'Blog' page.

After all that I entered some content in and it and tested and it didn't look right, none of my text was in there and a lowercase 'blog' was showing up for the title. I tested a bit more and found it was using the page.php file instead of my custom tpl-blog.php.

Thanks for any help!
Levi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the filename from `tpl-blog.php` to `page-blog.php`, see if that fixes it.

Comment: oh hmm, that fixed it. Was the fact that I set the page to be the 'Posts page' that gave the index.php template a higher precedence than the one I set in the admin? I had tried removing it as the 'Posts page' to see if that changed it and I still had the same problem. So basically I am not just wondering why the template being set in the admin wasn't given the highest precedent. Also, does this work because I am able to override template on a page-uri.php scheme? Good to know!

Comment: Yes, it's the filename that changes the template being used.  `tpl-blog.php` isn't a valid template filename.  You could override it with `blog.php` (as a page template, see twentyeleven for examples), as a template being set in the admin will override `page-blog.php`.  More info is available on the codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy