# Change default URL path (/blog/) of blog posts

Tags: urls

I've tried to research [prior questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58428/where-is-the-blog-url-set-from) on this topic but I believe that there was a better solution within the WordPress admin. How does one change the default URL path for blog posts?

It was previously */blog/title-of-post (but now the /blog/ part is gone).

Comment: Hi, are you asking about the permalinks? The question is a bit unclear to me. Can you please specify what do you want to achieve?

Comment: What is your permalink structure set to under Settings > Permalinks in admin?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create any structure you want for this on the permalinks settings page in the dashboard.

To set it to your example of /blog/title-of-post

Simply navigate to Settings -> Permalink.

Select the "Custom Structure" radio button and enter blog/%postname%/ into the text field there, then hit the save changes button.

Comment: Perfect, we had hidden Permalinks from the Settings menu because it wasn't relevant so this helped me to know what to go back and look for. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you

Comment: I can't find a "Settings -> Permalink" option on my wordpress.com site. Is it because I am using a free version?

Comment: Question: will this solution also make pages (that are not blog posts) appear with that "blog" path?